# jquery accessing php jason_encoded array

Tags: php, jquery

in test.php:

```
<?php
array_push($stack, "BLABLA");
array_push($stack, "BLABLA2");
echo json_encode($stack);
?>
```

in test.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post( 
    'test.php', // location of your php script
    {}, // any data you want to send to the script
    function( data ){  // a function to deal with the returned information
        $('#mydiv').html(data[0]).show();
    }, "json");
});
</script>

<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

I have done some sanity checks and it seems that data[0] isn't the correct way to access the first element I pushed in php. So how can I do this?

Comment: Did you know that your array is called `$stack`, but you are using `json_encode()` on a variable called `$array`?

Comment: can you post the json you are receiving from the server

Comment: I honestly don't know how to find that out! sorry very new to this.

Comment: @Kam inside the success event handler write `console.log(data)` and the  output will be printed to the firebug( for firefox) or chrome tools (for chrome) console. cpy from there and paste here...

Comment: @dakait! not only you gave me the solution, you also showed me how to debug!! Thank so much! the answer is that I wasn't declaring the array before I do array_push :$

Comment: @Kam glad ur prb is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<?php
    $stack = array();
    array_push($stack, "BLABLA");
    array_push($stack, "BLABLA2");
    echo json_encode($stack);
?>
```

and see it will surely give you `BLABLA` inside div with id `mydiv`.

Just define `$stack` as empty array first or make sure `$stack` array is already exists.

use [**firebug**](http://getfirebug.com/) Firefox add-on.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the data back into an array:

```
function( data ){  // a function to deal with the returned information
    data = JSON.parse(data); // convert the JSON data back to an array
    $('#mydiv').html(data[0]).show();
}, "json");
```